# Spring-MVC is adding on an extra .jsp extention to the URL a user enters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

The error message I get is description `The requested resource (/gradebook/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp.jsp) is not available`. I have a `WEB-INF/jsp` directory that contains `hello.jsp` Spring appears to be adding the jsp extension and I can't figure out why. I've pasted my `web.xml` and my `gradebook-servlet.xml` below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>gradebook</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>gradebook</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
      *index.jsp*
    </welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
  <bean name="/hello.htm" class="gradebook.web.HelloController"/>
<bean id="viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
        </property>
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring is adding ".jsp" because you've told it to - the `InternalResourceViewResolver` has been configured to add the ".jsp" suffix to whatever view name your controller returns.

I'm guessing your `HelloController` class is returning "hello.jsp" from its handler method? It should just be returning "hello", and Spring will append the ".jsp" as you've configured it.

Comment: Thanks, I was returning hello.jsp changing it to hello fixed the problem.